# Appropriate off-thread database interface for small apps in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sqlite, android-asynctask

I know there are a lot of threads relating to this topic on here, but I haven't read a real answer to my question, and a lot of them are from 2010 when there didn't seem to be as much emphasis on keeping tasks off the UI thread.

I need to make a database query that is just intensive enough that it causes a noticeable delay in UI response (on my S5, so it'd be worse on a lot of phones). I want to push the query to another thread. I've been doing so with ASyncTask, but I'm reading that there are issues with ASyncTask and things like the screen rotating, interrupting apps, and memory leaks. The recommendation I see everywhere is to use a CursorLoader, but the constructor for that requires a Uri because it's designed for content providers. Not only does a content provider seem like a bit of overkill for my app, but the content provider tutorial page from Google specifically states "You don't need a provider to use an SQLite database if the use is entirely within your own application."

So my question is what, if anything, lies between ASyncTask and a Content Provider? Is there any implementation of CursorLoader for internal databases? Maybe a more robust implementation of ASyncTask?

Comment: You may well want to create a Service and drive the service using a queue (that way you can reduce the amount of setup to connect to your database).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've been doing so with ASyncTask, but I'm reading that there are issues with ASyncTask and things like the screen rotating, interrupting apps, and memory leaks.

`AsyncTask` is a bit tricky to use properly. Having one be [managed by a retained fragment](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Threads/AsyncTask) (e.g., a model fragment) helps.

> Is there any implementation of CursorLoader for internal databases?

None that work well. I say this having written (and since deprecated) one. [The `Loader` interface is an abstraction designed around a singular use case: `ContentProvider`](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/03/31/cwac-loaderex-failed-abstractions.html).

> Maybe a more robust implementation of ASyncTask?

It's not that `AsyncTask` needs to be "more robust", but that you have to be aware of the various problems with it. For example, the vaunted `CursorLoader` uses an `AsyncTask`.

At the end of the day, all `AsyncTask` does is use a background thread from a thread pool and mediate communications back to the main application thread for the results of the work. There are any number of ways of accomplishing the same end. Presently, I'm fond of using [greenrobot's EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) (or one from a thread pool, if there might be lots of simultaneous events), in conjunction with [an ordinary thread](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/AsyncDemo). Beyond that, you can:

- Use an ordinary thread with a `Handler`
- Use an ordinary thread with `post()` on a `View`
- Use an ordinary thread with `runOnUiThread()` on an `Activity`

And all of those presume that the work is reasonably short and disposable, as would appear to be your case. For longer and/or less-disposable bits of work, use an `IntentService`, possibly [my `WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) if the work might take dozens of seconds or more.

However, all of these still have issues, in some cases the same issues that `AsyncTask` itself has (e.g., addressing configuration changes properly). There is no "silver bullet".

Comment: Thanks. Just after I posted this I found an article about using AsyncTask in a retained fragment and I think that will work well. I had looked into bus implementation but again it seemed overly complicated for one database query.